# How to execute a click to call href:tel with a AJAX Post/Put?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I post before the default browser click to call? The default browser action stops the posting action. I do not get data in the `console.log`.

```
<a id="callButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="tel:+1-999-115-4490">Call Customer Support/a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#callButton").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'foo',
            data: 'ok',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to prevent the default event using `preventDefault()`. Then in the callback of your AJAX you can redirect to the `href` specified in the `a` element. Try this:

```
$("#callButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the default event
    var $a = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'foo',
        data: 'ok',
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.assign($a.attr('href')); // redirect to the URL after the AJAX completes.
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault()`; and then re-enable it using `$("callbutton").unbind("click", preventDefault);`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#callButton").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'foo',
            data: 'ok',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $(self).unbind('click', preventDefault());
            },
            error: function(jqXHR) {
                $(self).unbind('click', preventDefault());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `e.preventDefault();` to disable the default browser behaviour, grab the `href` value and use it together with the `window.location.href` like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#callButton").click(function(e){
    // Prevent default click behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the link
    var link = $(this).attr("href");

    // Post data
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://posttestserver.com/post.php',
        data: "ok",
        success: function(data) {
          console.info(data);
        }
      });
    }, 1);

    // Click the link    
    window.location.href = link;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind all href="tel:*" attribute tags by using below code

```
$("a[href^='tel:']").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the default event
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'your_request_url.php', // your request URL
        data: {number: $this.attr('href').replace('tel:','')},
        success: function(data) {
              // handle your success response
        }
    });
});
```